# Why cannot find declaration to go to in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, go

I have a code in go, and I am using IntelliJIdea for development. It used to work fine, but since the time I have changed the folder where the code used to be, IntelliJ has been behaving in a weird manner. It shows me a lot of `unable to find declaration to go to errors`. After changing the folder where my project used to be, I changed the GOPATH and imported from the new directory once again.

I am attaching the screenshot as that will be better for understanding.

[See the conductor.Start(). This function is right there in the package app. But it can't find this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gUUf.png)

PS: I have tried importing the project from scratch and invalidating and restarting multiple times, but that didn't help.

Comment: List your $GOPATH environment variable.

Comment: @eduncan911, the GOPATH that is set on my system is: `/Users/<username>/Desktop/Work/Cloud/godir`. And my project is at, `/Users/<username>Desktop/Work/Cloud/godir/src/stash/cloud/conduc`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ cannot find any declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282285/intellij-cannot-find-any-declarations)

Comment: Did you set the correct Interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Gogland, which is also a JetBrains IDE, but I also had a problem with symbols not getting resolved.

I fixed it by deleting the project's index file.

1. Close the IDE.
2. In your project directory, find a directory named ".idea".
3. Delete all files with the extension ".iml" in that directory.
4. Restart the IDE.

The project should get reindexed and symbols will be resolved.

https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/project_structure.html?search=.iml

Comment: this worked. However, I had to perform one additional step after 4, to manually add back .iml file, as it was not created automatically.

Comment: I also had to manually put back the .iml file but it still didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, Intellij didn't have Rust installed. I found that out while trying to create a new project (it had JAVA and other language support). As soon as I installed Rust, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

For my case, I have 2 virtual environments, and I found that I did not set the correct environment in Pycharm. The environment I used did not include these packages. After I changed the environment, everything goes well.