# Intellij Cannot find declaration to go to

Tags: intellij-idea

I am working with a scala project, this is my spec:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.6183.87, built on March 27, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b39 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.4
```

I cannot click on declarations and it is frustrating me!

I know that this question already have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282285/intellij-cannot-find-any-declarations) but the solutions provided are not working and i am desperate, i tried:

```
File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Mark src folder as root source folder

Exit IDE
Recursively delete all .iml files from project directory
Find and delete all .idea folders
Delete contents of the caches, index, and LocalHistory folders under .IntelliJIdea2017.2\system
Open Idea and import project ....
```

And it is not working.

Comment: Is it reproducible with every project, even new simple one?

Comment: I have tried creating a new one from scratch, and it is working, but the another project is not working. I can run the project, but i can't go to declarations.

Comment: I have deleted and reinstalled IntelliJ. I can't go to declarations. Do i have to create another project from scratch and copy/paste the files with code and build.sbt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the value of the name attribute of the build.sbt file, that is, I changed a character, I saved, I put the character back, I saved again, the project has recompiled and now if it finds the sources, the packages, everything.

I don't get it, actually, but it works and I can continue.

Answer (score 0):

intelliJ had disassociated .php files as PHP files, and instead as text files for some reason.

Going to Prefs -> File Types and adding back *.php as a PHP file type fixed all my problems.