# Intellij IDEA : Cannot find declaration to go to in Java Project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

**Ctrl B** (go to declaration), doesn't work with Intellij IDE latest version, already done with invalidating caches/restart.

**Intellij IDEA version: 2019.2.3, OS -Windows 10**

**PS:** I have gone through other links and tried to invalidate caches and restart options as well as deleting `iml` files.

Comment: tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50868987 actually this worked for me

Comment: yes , indeed , I went through almost all the links those state this problem.

Comment: Is it a maven project? Does the IDE shows functions as red?

Comment: No,its a simple java project. I tried these options for maven project as well but no luck.

Comment: IDE doesnt show functions as red , but while I right click and say Go to , then it doesnt work