# IntelliJ: Cannot find declaration to go to in Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, intellij-idea

In my `activity_main.xml` I have a TextView:

```
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/str" />
```

In my `MainActivity.kt` I have declared:

```
str.setText("Changed")
```

IntelliJ says that it cannot find declaration to go to. How can I fix this? I have looked to other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282285/intellij-cannot-find-any-declarations) and they do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How silly of me... All I had to do was to add this line of code:

```
val str = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.str)
```